# WordPress gives 500 server error after changing the site url to work with Weglot translation plugin

Tags: php, wordpress

I am a new WordPress user and recently I added **Weglot** multilingual support to my website. I wanted to have English as my default URL so I foolishly try to change the **site address URL and WordPress address URL** at Settings->General to `https://example.com/en`, which started the problem, I was not able to access WordPress itself.

Then I changed the WordPress address URL and site address URL in the **WordPress database wp_options table**. Now I am able to access WordPress but my other pages or the URL generated by Weglot to support multilingual stuff like `https://example.com/en/servizi/` is not loading and giving the same error as below:

> Internal Server Error The server encountered an internal error or
> misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request.
>
> Please contact the server administrator at [no address given] to
> inform them of the time this error occurred, and the actions you
> performed just before this error.
>
> More information about this error may be available in the server error
> log.
>
> Additionally, a 500 Internal Server Error error was encountered while
> trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.
>
> Apache/2.4.41 Server at example.com Port 443

And when I checked respective pages, it shows below error for **wp-asset-clean-up**: CSS and javascript manager plugin.

> Note: The checked URL returned an error when fetching the assets via
> AJAX call. This could be because of a firewall that is blocking the
> AJAX call, a redirect loop or an error in the script that is
> retrieving the output which could be due to an incompatibility between
> the plugin and the WordPress setup you are using.
>
> Here is the response from the call:
>
> Status Code Error: 500 * for more information about client and server
> errors, check this link Suggestion: Select “WP Remote Post” as a
> method of retrieving the assets from the “Settings” page. If that
> doesn’t fix the issue, just use “Manage in Front-end” option which
> should always work and submit a ticket about your problem. Output:
> Internal Server Error The server encountered an internal error or
> misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request.
>
> Please contact the server administrator at [no address given] to
> inform them of the time this error occurred, and the actions you
> performed just before this error.
>
> More information about this error may be available in the server error
> log.
>
> Additionally, a 500 Internal Server Error error was encountered while
> trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.
>
> Apache/2.4.41 Server at example.com Port 443

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you flush your permalinks? Go to Wordpress admin -> Settings -> Permalinks and click save, It should flush your permalinks.

After that check your .htaccess, I had simular issue once and I had to change the .htaccess to work properly.

This seems like a problem from .htaccess...
First check If .htaccess looks like this.

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /
    RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

After that try this solution, this worked for me once when I had that issue.

```
DirectoryIndex index.php
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^index.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ ./index.php [L]
```

Then check your apache logs via ssh

```
sudo tail /var/log/apache2/error.log
```

Last thing I recommend If you have any cache plugins disable them.
Oh and all the time try to flush your permalinks.

Comment: Many thanks, it loads properly now, but the home page English version(Default is Italian) could not able to load JS, CSS, and Images. It gives 404 not found error. Any idea @Pipo

Comment: sounds like you need to setup in settings your main language

Comment: No worry, I am done. There was some issue in some plugins and wrong data in the database. I have deactivated all plugins by changing plugin folder name in wp-content directory to plugin_deactivated and changing it back to plugin, so as to activating plugin one by one which updates the data in the database with fresh data as well. That solves my problem. But anyway.. many thanks to you for Permalinks thingy. That saves my day. :) Good Day @Pipo

Comment: Glad it helped :)

Answer (score 1):

**1. Set your WP urls correctly**

Firstly, you haven't moved the location of the WP installation, so your **Site URL** shouldn't change. If you want the WP site to run from /en by default, then you only need to change your **Home URL**.

- WP_SITEURL: https://example.com/
- WP_HOME : https://example.com/en/

**2. Change all the URLs in the database**

WP websites store a lot of full URLs in the database, and changing the site & home URLs doesn't change the URLs in the db entries.

I assume you need to change all your urls to use `/en/` for the site to work (that's specific to the plugin so I can only guess based on your question) - if so you need to find all the URLs in the database that use `https://example.com/` and replace them with `https://example.com/en/`.

You could do this manually, but it can be tricky so my suggestion is to use a plugin such as which will find and change all the URLs. The one I use is [Better Search Replace](https://wordpress.org/plugins/better-search-replace/) but there are others.

**Make a backup first!** Of course, before you do this make sure you make a backup - once you change the database, you can't just undo those changes!

I'm not familiar this plugin, so I'm not sure if there are plugin-specific changes after that - that's a question for the plugin support as its specific to that plugin and is beyond the scope of how we can help out here. But those steps should get you back up & running again anyway.

**TIP - resetting your Home and Site URLs after making a mistake**

If you change your Home and Site URLs and can no longer get the site to work, you can override the WP Home and Site address URLs in your `wp-config.php` file - just add these lines near the top:

```
define('WP_HOME','https://example.com/');
define('WP_SITEURL','https://example.com/');
```

Now you can get back into the admin and website,  to fix whatever changes you made.